# Getting error on binding param in select statement in MySQLi

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have added a select snippet below. Why am I getting the following error on `bind_param()`?

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean

Code:

```
$sessien = $_POST['xsession'];
$conn = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
$query = "SELECT `post` FROM `user` WHERE session=? ORDER BY `thedate` DESC ";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $sessien);
$stmt->execute();
while ($stmt -> fetch()) {
        echo "$post<br>";
}
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
```

Comment: _"mysqli_prepare() returns a statement object or FALSE if an error occurred."_

Comment: but the log is showing error on binding not preparing

Comment: Run `var_dump($stmt);` after the prepare and you'll understand.

Answer (score 1):

Mysqli prepare can returns `false` before bind you must check it for errors.
look at this article in php.net

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

```
    $sessien = $_POST['xsession'];
    $conn = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    /* check connection */
    if ($conn->connect_errno) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $conn->connect_error);
        exit();
    }
    $query = "SELECT `post` FROM `user` WHERE session=? ORDER BY `thedate` DESC ";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    if ($stmt) {
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $sessien);

        //bind Response variables
        $stmt->bind_result($post);
        $stmt->execute();
        while ($stmt -> fetch()) {
                echo "$post<br>";
        }
        $stmt->close();
    }else{
           //error
           var_dump($conn->error);
    }
```

Comment: weird! now I am getting undefined variable `query`

Comment: @MonaCoder probably you have an error in typing.
`$query` first defined and used and we should not have this error . I just run this code in my device and it haven't error. code was eddited

Comment: @MonaCoder i was create a DB in my machine and this code works good in my machine without error. check your database connection and Table structure !

Comment: I am using `$query` for sure in both `$query = "...";` and `prepare($query)` and getting this error `Undefined variable: query`

Comment: but passing the select string in directly inside the `prepare()` is working!